# cogent.db.ensembl cookbook's example of .getGeneByStableId() returns 'ProgrammingError'

Tags: python, database, database-connection, bioinformatics, cookbook

I get an error using PyCogent to query EnsEMBl's database - could this bug result from updates in EnsEMBL or PyCogent?

When trying to reproduce the code for the PyCogent Cookbook's [Querying Ensembl](http://pycogent.org/examples/query_ensembl.html#query-ensembl) doc page  ("Selecting Gene's" section) I get *"ProgrammingError".*

[image]

**Here's the failing cookbook code** (I indicate the line where error occurs):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Interrogating a Genome
#----------------------------------------------------------
from cogent.db.ensembl import HostAccount, Genome
human = Genome(Species='human', Release=Release, account=account)

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Selecting Genes
#----------------------------------------------------------
brca1 = human.getGeneByStableId(StableId='ENSG00000012048') #<--- ERRORS OUT HERE
print brca1.Description
```

**Here's the error:**

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'homo_sapiens_variation_74_37.flanking_sequence' doesn't exist") 'DESCRIBE flanking_sequence' ()
```

**Extra info:**

- Python 2.7.3
- PyCogent 1.5.1-2
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Ensmbl release 74

Comment: cross posted on biostars: http://www.biostars.org/p/90804/

Answer (score 1):

That error arises because Ensembl dropped the flanking_seq database from release 70 on. This issue was fixed in the PyCogent github repository.